# Возможно ли объединить несколько строк в одну?

Tags: python

```
s = s.replace("а", "")
s = s.replace("у", "")
s = s.replace("о", "")
s = s.replace("ы", "")
s = s.replace("и", "")
s = s.replace("э", "")
s = s.replace("я", "")
s = s.replace("ю", "")
s = s.replace("ё", "")
s = s.replace("е", "")
```

Как объединить в одну строку?

Comment: да, regex вам в помощь

Comment: можно поподробнее, что такое regex?

Comment: регулярные выражения

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вариант решения с использованием регулярных выражений:

```
import re

res = re.sub(r"[ауоыиэяюёе]", "", s)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
res = s.translate(str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys(list("ауоыиэяюёе"), "")))
```

еще лучше воспользоваться советом от уважаемого @extrn:

```
res = s.translate(str.maketrans("", "", "ауоыиэяюёе"))
```

PS [из документации по `str.maketrans(x, y, z)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans):

> if there is a third argument, it must be a string, whose characters
> will be mapped to None in the result.

Comment: еще вариант.`s.translate(str.maketrans("", "", "ауоыиэяюёе"))`

Comment: @extrn, спасибо, не знал про третий параметр у `str.maketrans()`!

Answer (score 5):

можно так:

```
s = "".join(i for i in s if i not in "ауоыиэяюёе")
```

Либо так :)

```
s = s.replace("а", "").replace("у", "").replace("о", "").replace("ы", "").replace("и", "").replace("э", "").replace("я", "").replace("ю", "").replace("ё", "").replace("е", "")
```